# Is the Geocoder API free in Android?

Tags: android, geocoding

I want to know whether the [built-in Geocoding API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder) is free or not.

I found [this price sheet](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-and-billing) but not sure that it is referring to the class above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in geocoder is free, but it has been said to have a limit which depends on the implementation. However as it says in the documentation, there isn't always one available for every device, so you might want to fall back on the Google Maps API.

Comment: Thanks! But how can i find the limits, Henry?

Comment: Well it could be completely different per device, so you'd have to ask each device maker separately. That's why I would recommend having a fall back.